# AngularJS script tag JSON-LD

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, json-ld

How do you create an `application/ld+json` `script` tag with a dynamically built JSON object in AngularJS .

This is what I need the script tag to look like

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Place",
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": "40.75",
    "longitude": "73.98"
  },
  "name": "Empire State Building"
}
</script>
```

I have tried the following code but I cant get it to work:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <script type="application/ld+json">
    {{jsonId|json}}
  </script>
  {{jsonId|json}}
</div>
```

Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('application', []);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.jsonId = {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Place",
    "geo": {
      "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
      "latitude": "40.75",
      "longitude": "73.98"
    },
    "name": "Empire State Building"
  };
}]);
```

The expression inside the script tag does not execute.
The expression outside the script tag executes correctly and displays the JSON

Please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqz31net/)

Comment: how can you tell if it executes or not? it's just an anon object...

Comment: @dandavis `json` is a filter that outputs the JSON object. There is no JSON object between the script tags if you view the source.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After a cup of coffee I remembered there is a `$sce` service with a `trustAsHtml` function.

I created a directive that accepts a `json` parameter for easy re-use

Please see updated and working code below:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <jsonld data-json="jsonId"></jsonld>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('application', []);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.jsonId = {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Place",
    "geo": {
      "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
      "latitude": "40.75",
      "longitude": "73.98"
    },
    "name": "Empire State Building"
  };
}]).directive('jsonld', ['$filter', '$sce', function($filter, $sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: function() {
      return '<script type="application/ld+json" ng-bind-html="onGetJson()"></script>';
    },
    scope: {
      json: '=json'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.onGetJson = function() {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml($filter('json')(scope.json));
      }
    },
    replace: true
  };
}]);
```

Here is a image of the script output

Please see updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqz31net/1/)

[image]

Comment: How I can achieve same in the Angularjs 2.

Comment: @ArvindChavhan It seems like script tags are removed in angular2 if they are inside you template html, here is a question regarding the issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088996/adding-script-tags-in-angular2-component-template and here is the link to the bug/feature request https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9695

Comment: @Tjaart van der Walt Hi, sorry my question might sound stupid but I have an app that lazy loads some jobs do I have to include all the jobs to the script for it to work?

Comment: @MohamedMahmoud If you need all the jobs to be displayed in the JSON-LD tag then yes you will need to include them all in the JSON output. I would rather show the latest jobs in the script tag or let the script tag show the same initial data that your page is showing on initial load. This way you don't abuse the tag with too much data.

Answer (score 1):

Tjaart van der Walt's answer did not work for me in the [Google Test Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/). It did work with the real crawler.
So I found another "old-school" solution which did the trick:

HTML

```
<script type="application/ld+json" id="json-ld-music-group"></script>
```

Angular

```
var schemaOrg = angular.toJson({
    '@context': 'http://schema.org',
    '@type': 'MusicGroup',
    ...
});

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    var jsonLd = angular.element(document.getElementById('json-ld-music-group'))[0];
    jsonLd.innerHTML = schemaOrg;
});
```

Comment: I disagrea as we use this solution in "real case scenario" as you stated. Please click on the following link https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2Fvqz31net%2F1%2F this will launch googles structure data testing tool with the example jsfiddle in my answer. You will see Place is detected on the right hand side. Ignore the errors as that is jsfiddles website data and not the example jsfiddle. Are you sure you did not try and test a localhost website?

Comment: You are right. It worked after all. Google had a delay in processing the results of 5 days. It just did not work in the Google Test tool for me. I edited my earlier comment.