# schema not detected in google structured-data testing-tool

Tags: angular, schema.org, jsonschema, structured-data

I have added `itemtype="http://schema.org/Restaurant"` schema in my angular 2 website. I tested with https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ but my page content not rendered in google testing tool. it is displayong like `<my-app>Loading...</my-app>`. I have checked in console html is rendered. I want to display the rednred html in google testing tool. How to fix this?. Please help with this.

```
    <div  class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 " itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Restaurant">
        <div  class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 ">
            <div  class="summary">
                <div  class="hidden"> <img  itemprop="image" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/cj17j9p8ia2324p/13531992_1727289640876806_1806315202_n.jpg?raw=1"></div>   
                <div  class="hidden" itemprop="name">Chicks On Fire</div>   
                <h1  class="">Summary</h1>
                <p  class="" itemprop="description">item description.</p>
            </div>
            <div  class="sum_details ">
                <div  class="address">
                    <span  class="icon-address"><img  alt="Activity" class="icon1" src="assets/images/korean.png" title="Activity"></span>
                    <p  class="address_title" itemprop="servesCuisine">Western</p>
                </div>
                <div  class="address">
                    <span  class="icon-address"><img  alt="Food Category" class="icon1" src="assets/images/tick.png" title="Food Category"></span>
                    <p  class="address_title">Halal meat</p>
                </div>
                <div  class="address">
                    <span  class="icon-address"><img  alt="Timing" class="icon1" src="assets/images/time.png" title="Timing"></span>
                    <p  class="address_title">1800 - 2200</p>
                    <div  itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
                        <span  class="hidden" itemprop="opens" content="1800">1800</span>
                        <span  class="hidden" itemprop="closes" content="2200">2200</span>
                    </div>

                    <p  class="address_title">Closed on Mondays.</p>

                </div>
                <div  class="address">
                    <span  class="icon-address"><img  alt="Pricing" class="icon1" src="assets/images/tag.png" title="Pricing"></span>
                    <p  class="address_title" itemprop="priceRange">20-30 GBP</p>
                </div>                    
                <div  class="address">
                    <span  class="icon-address"><img  alt="Website" class="icon1" src="assets/images/website.png" title="Website"></span>
                    <p  class="address_title"><a  itemprop="url" target="_Blank" href="http://www.mysite.co.uk/">Visit website</a></p>
                </div>
                <div  class="address">
                    <span  class="icon-address"><img  alt="Location" class="icon1" src="assets/images/location.png" title="Location"></span>
                    <p  class="address_title " itemprop="address">11 Hercules St, London Borough of Islington, London</p>

                </div>
            </div>                        
        </div>           
    </div>
```

**google testing tool result**

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <base href="/planner/">
    <script>
      (function() {
        window['_app_base'] = '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
      })();
    </script>
      <title></title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');   
      ga('create', 'UA-5257', 'none');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <link href="styles.dbb24ce5e4a005ec7903.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
    <body> 
      <my-app>Loading...</my-app>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.ca338d2ec972840d9759.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.507dd0128897cd6bbb86.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.d72da31d6e50a2a57f34.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.6456ae999bcbe35f9e26.bundle.js"></script></body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So you want to keep requiring JavaScript for showing your data, but you are looking for a way to test it in SDTT anyway (even if the Googlebot won’t see it)?

Comment: @unor, how to keep keep requiring JavaScript?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. -- In other words: Google’s SDTT doesn’t support running JavaScript for parsing Microdata, and as far as we know, Googlebot doesn’t support it either. So what do you want to do now? Change your site so that it doesn’t require JavaScript, or keep it like that but find a way to test your Microdata in the SDTT (which wouldn’t help Googlebot)?

Comment: @unor, I want display the schema tags in SDTT. it is working in PHP and wordpress site.

Comment: @unor, I didnt get you clearly. could you please elaborate ?

Comment: "I want display the schema tags in SDTT": If you copy-paste the HTML from the console, it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146060/discussion-between-vel-and-unor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about Angular2 is that when fired up, all content inside your root app-element goes away. This means that you can put whatever you want in there from the server which you want to be picked up by crawlers.

You can generate this content by using a server-rendered version of the content in your app, or have custom logic.

You can find some more information here: https://angularu.com/VideoSession/2015sf/angular-2-server-rendering and here: https://github.com/angular/universal

[Angular2 SEO - How to make an angular 2 app crawlable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914371/angular2-seo-how-to-make-an-angular-2-app-crawlable)