# How to use interpolation in javascript <script> tag in Angular 1?

Tags: angularjs, interpolation, script-tag, angular1.6

I would like to use the `{{}}` interpolation operator in a `<script>` tag in a `.html` file using Angular 1.5 as shown with the `::job.name` example below. Would appreciate suggestions. The JSON object must be declared inside the `<script>` tag as shown below

The use of `job.brand_name` works below, but `job.name` does not.

```
<script type="application/json"> {
  "title" : "{{::job.name}}"
}
</script>


<p>{{::job.brand_name}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use string interpolation within a script tag. 
I have impression you are trying to make a crawlable content and build `json+ld` code.

You should consider building a custom directive as answered here [AngularJS script tag JSON-LD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332430/angularjs-script-tag-json-ld) It will work for regular JSON too.